# Power management for a 5V 12A load

Tags: power-supply, power, current, voltage-regulator, heatsink

I need to deal with a peak load at 5VDC and about 11.25A but I'm not sure how to manage this.

I have 5 individual loads of 2.25A and small loads from an MCU and some LEDs all of which should fit into the 12A. Another requirement that I have is that power supply can be placed in a sealed enclosure so that it can be placed outside and not have water get in. I suppose an aluminum case might help with this.

I am not quite confident enough to build my own power supply. Dealing with mains is a bit scary. I've found some [a RC car battery charger power supplies that will supply 14VDC @ 16A (Turnigy T-20Pro)](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__13765__Turnigy_T_20Pro_Quality_16A_Power_Supply_180_240V_220W_.html). They have fans in them which wouldn't do much being in a sealed enclosure. My though was that I could use simple 5V linear regulators for each of the 2.25A loads and another for the MCU and LEDs.

What alternatives do I have and/or what trouble am I going to run into?

**UPDATE:**
I wasn't explicit about the power source, sorry. It will be 120v 60Hz AC.

**UPDATEv2:**
Most of the load (5x2.25A=11.25A) will be outside the enclosure as the project is a LED Christmas light controller.

Comment: Linear regulators dissipate a lot of power as heat: `P = dV x I`, so if you are driving 5 Volts 2.25 Amperes off a 12 volt supply, each linear regulator will need to dissipate 15.75 Watts as heat, without exceeding the maximum junction temperature of the part. This isn't a good way to go, even if you could find a part meeting that set of specifications.

Comment: You may be able to use a normal PC/LAPTOP power supply.  If the 5V can't supply the current you need, then another DC-DC converter from 12 to 5v.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh \$\Delta\$ is more approprate here ;o) \$\text{\$\Delta\$}\$ And yes I am aware you can't change it, but I just couldn't resist mentioning it.

Comment: A big question is: what is your power source?  AC, car battery?  Your question is pretty vague on that point.

Comment: I wasn't explicit about the power source, sorry. It will be 120v 60Hz AC.

Comment: Are the loads going to be in the same enclosure as the power supply?  External?  Daisy chained?

Comment: @TobyLawrence That is all up for discussion.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not comfortable working with mains voltage, and assuming that your loads are in the same enclosure as your power supply (i.e. you're generating a lot of heat in an enclosure), you might consider a AC->DC power supply mounted remotely from your enclosure, and running 5V into your enclosure.

Normally, voltage droop would be a concern under such use cases, as it only takes 0.04 ohm of line resistance to drop 10% of your supply voltage.  Many power supplies have remote sense leads, such that the power supply closes its control loop around the supply voltage at your enclosure, compensating for any transmission losses.

The benefits of this approach include reduced power dissipation in your outdoor enclosure and only hand-friendly 5V in the enclosure (but watch out for shorts!).  The downsides are the need for a separate (hopefully indoor-rated) enclosure for the supply and possibly a slightly higher cost for a AC-DC supply with remote sense capability.

Comment: To compact on this, I'd recommend the same, but you could probably boost the voltage.  Power over Ethernet runs at a nominal voltage of somewhere around 50VDC and is pretty darn safe.. you certainly don't see people dying from it, or anything.  This will give you the benefit of being able to run smaller/lighter cabling while still maintaining a relatively low voltage drop.  It also gives you more headroom for conversion at the point of load.

Comment: Agreed.  I had assumed that the OP was price sensitive and might want to avoid double conversion, but you're right that it might pay for itself in the cost of copper cabling.

Comment: @TobyLawrence, 50 V is generally considered the maximum voltage that's safe to touch. If you put you elbow on ground and your fingers (of the same hand) on 50 V, you're likely to feel anything from a light tingle to an unpleasant buzz, depending on how damp your skin is. This is why (and also a legacy in the telphone system) you see a lot of power distribution at 48 V.

Comment: That said, **don't** go wet your hands and put one on ground and the other on 50 V. You'll very likely do no damage, but you'd be taking a chance.

Answer (score 2):

Building your own AC-DC power supply will be quite tricky.  As others mentioned, you won't be able to do this easily with a linear regulator, and it's just not worth designing a SMPS on your own.  After all, computer power supply units regularly provide lots of current on the 5V rail (20 A is typical), and they are very cheap.

Since you need to be outdoors, I suggest looking for a fanless ATX power supply, so that it can be sealed in a case.  You may be able to get away with a regular power supply with a fan if the case can be used as a heat sink, and because the load will be low compared to a computer.  It's even safe to test, since power supplies have an integrated thermal shutoff if they overheat.  This [datasheet](http://www.hoffmanonline.com/stream_document.aspx?rRID=233309&pRID=162533) on thermal management suggests you will need a case with an internal surface area of at least 4 square feet to manage a 60 W load without ventilation. In practice, you probably need more.

When looking for a computer power supply for this job, keep in mind that many newer ones provide only a +12V rail and use a DC-DC switcher on the mainboard.  Look for an older one with a dedicated +5V rail.

To make a computer supply work in this way, you need to have a way to toggle its "power button" signal.  Have a look at the ATX connector pinout to see what's required.  You could make it a switch, or use a pulldown resistor to make it permanently on.

I believe you should also put small dummy loads on the other power rails, because some power supplies don't behave well when they are completely unloaded.  Usually the +5V rail is the one used for regulating the supply, so you shouldn't have trouble on that front.  Also keep in mind that most power supplies have a standby +5V that has a low current limit; you won't want to use that.

Comment: The ATX power supply was my 1st thought when designing this, but I wasn't sure about the heat management with it being outside. I've hacked an ATX power supply before and am comfortable with all of the power on stuff. Thanks for the datasheet on thermal management. This is a Christmas light controller project and I live in the Pacific Northwest so external ambient temperatures would be usually below 50°F (10°C). The is a bunch of moisture which is why I wanted a sealed enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

Exterior power supplies are a big challenge because they need to be sealed (to keep rain / snow / dust / dirt out) which compromises cooling (forced air doesn't really help) plus they need to withstand some extreme temperature swings (-40C to +50C isn't uncommon) which limits you in some nasty ways (most electrolytic capacitors significantly lose their capacitance below 0C).

[Off-the-shelf](http://aidisenled.en.alibaba.com/product/608715940-210697512/waterproof_led_power_supply_CE_ROHS_5V_20W_.html) exterior LED power supplies are probably your best bet. (Make sure you find one that's safety-approved, unlike the example I cited!)